# How to position the cursor caret in Xcode code snippets

Tags: xcode, code-snippets

Is it possible to specify where the cursor should be after inserting a code snippet in xcode 4?  Is there a <# #> style marker for this?  I'm having trouble finding good documentation on code snippets.

Answer (score 14):

You can just use `<##>`. It will show a "bubble" you can select, which isn't ideal, but it does move the cursor caret to that location.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple examples supplementing @rdougan's helpful answer. This is not exactly what the OP was asking in the question, but it is what I was looking for when I came here based on the title.

## Custom Example

```
print("<#text#>")
```

gives you

[image]

## Standard Example

You can also observe any of the standard code snippets to see how they are made. Just click one of them in the code snippet area.

[image]

which gives

[image]

## Reminder on how to add custom code snippets:

Write your code as normal in the code editor. Then highlight it and drag it into the code snippet window. A dialog box will pop up where you can give it a simple shortcut.

[image]